# How to model relationships changing one to one relationships with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, orm, data-modeling, foreign-key-relationship

I have 2 entities plug and socket which have one to one mapping.

Now, plug has a foreign key relationship to the socket it is plugged in to.

Hibernate generates unique constraint on the foreign key so as to ensure a one-to-one particpation.

I have say 10 plugs which are plugged into 10 sockets.

After some time, an update comes which informs the system about the change in arrangement.

The scenario is plugA which was plugged in to socketA is now plugged into SocketB and plugB which was plugged into SocketB is now plugged into socketA.

When doing the update, hibernate first tries to update plugA's foreign key column to SocketB which results in the violation of unique constraint. This is because the plugB to socketB relationship has not yet ben altered.

What is the most correct way to model the relationship?

Note that entire update needs to occur as a single transaction.

This is the code

Inside socket

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="socket")
public Plug getPlug()
{
   return plug;
}
```

Inside Plug 
    @OneToOne(optional=false) 
    public Socket getSocket()
    {
       return socket;
    }

Comment: why dont you do it many to one ? many plugs for a socket

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you either have 2 transactions like

```
first transction :  
set both plug.socket to null

second transaction:  
set both plug.socket to what you eventually want
```

or

use `many-to-one`

Comment: What you describe is the approach for me right now.

However, what happens when second transaction fails due to some violation?

Is there a way in Hibernate to have an overarching transaction, that  can take me back to over to the initial state?

Answer (score 0):

I liked your question so I had to try and solve it. So I hope you haven't figured it out on your own yet.. :)

So what you need to do is something like this:

```
@Override
public void swap(Socket s1, Socket s2) {
    s1 = em.find(Socket.class, s1.getId());
    s2 = em.find(Socket.class, s2.getId());
    Plug plug1 = s1.getPlug();
    Plug plug2 = s2.getPlug();
    plug1.setSocket(null); //This is to avoid duplicate key exception
    plug2.setSocket(null);
    em.flush(); //Without this the nullifying will just be overwritten by the next change.
    plug1.setSocket(s2);
    plug2.setSocket(s1);

}
```

Now with this its important that the socket field is nullable/optional. So you have to remove the `optional=true`. But that leaves you without a unique constraint which can lead to inconsistency as the relationship effectively becomes a one to many.. So what you do is this:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(nullable=true, unique=true)
private Socket socket;
```

So the only problem left is that you now are allowed to persist a Plug without a socket. This should not be a big problem and can easily be prevented/validated in you DAO.